# Setting shipping programmatically when product is added to cart?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-methods

**Magento 1.7**

This is the code which gets called via the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event when I add a product to the cart:

```
function addProductComplete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $onepage = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
        $onepage->saveShippingMethod("flatrate_flatrate");

        // Add address to cart
        $address = $onepage->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

        if (null == $address->getCountryId())
        {
            $country = Mage::helper('core')->getDefaultCountry(); // use default country
            if ( '' == $country )
            {
                $country = 'DE';
            }
            $address->setCountryId($country);
        }

        if ( null == $address->getPostcode() )
        {
            $address->setPostcode('00000');
        }
        $address->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
        $address->setCollectShippingrates(true);

        // save settings
        $onepage->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
        $onepage->getQuote()->save();

    }
```

When I add the first product, nothing happens, only after adding the second product, it works. I guess thats because the first time there is no quote object? How to solve that so it works with the first product as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with sales_quote_product_add_after instead of checkout_cart_product_add_after